# How to use uglify to minimise files in play 2.4

Tags: playframework, minify, uglifyjs

I was trying to minify files in my play project.
Play version - 2.4.

I added the plugin in build.sbt using this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")
```

And  also added it in pipeline by adding:

```
pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(uglify, digest) in build.sbt
```

The digest plugin works fine. However, uglify command does nothing. What are the right steps to minify the files?

Comment: Are you trying to access `.min.js` files? Have you seen [sbt-uglify docs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify)?

Comment: @marcospereira I am not able to minify the files. I used the above steps and then uglify command but it did not work. I have read the documentation but it didn't work.